# Pyspark: how to read a .csv file?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to read a .csv file that has a strange format.

This is what I am doing

```
df =  spark.read.format('csv').option("header", "true").option("delimiter", ',').load("muyFile.csv"))
df.show(5)
```

[image]

I do not understand why the `lonlat` entry of the third id is transposed. It seems that the file has two different delimiters. Your help would be much appreciated!

Comment: This is a data issue then. Please check your data..

Comment: Your `tags` column seems to have separators in the value. What if you add `.option("quote","\"")`?

Answer (score 0):

your tag field probably contains comma as a value which is treated as the delimiter.
enclose your data in quotes or any other quote char(remember to set .option('quote','')) and read the data again. It should work